# How do I create panes within a Nautilus window?

Tags: nautilus

This morning my cat discovered a Nautilus feature I wasn't aware of. By sitting on my keyboard she split the Nautilus window into two panes. I am now at the office without my cat and unable to repeat the procedure. Is there a way to achieve this without a cat?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open Nautilus and press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Or **`View-->Extra Pane`**  As in the picture.
[image]

Comment: I liked it more with the humour.

Comment: no more available in v. 3.10

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the <kbd>F3</kbd> key press, you can also open the extra pane from the menu via mouse. View > Extra Pane.

Answer (score 5):

You can also switch between panes with <kbd>F6</kbd>, create new tab in each of the two panes, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>, and navigate through tab of a pane with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.