# Is there a way to turn Nautilus into dual pane manager

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create panes within a Nautilus window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55446/how-do-i-create-panes-within-a-nautilus-window)

I want to add/edit NAutilus actions. I know how to add a custom command, just dont know the syntax of the commands:

```
Open dir in current window Cntr+number(for each location)
Copy to other pane F5
Move to other pane F6
New dir f7
```

and others
I would like to start nautilus in dual pane mode by default.
A link with Nautilus commands available will be very helpful.

Comment: When I mean dual pane manager, I mean sunflower and Krusader. The question and the answers you consider this question is a possible duplicate to, do not talk about this.